# what is the right syntax for a JSON encoded PUT request using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, request, put

I write my ajax PUT request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url_lab_data+"backend/read/{\"f_anid\":"+anid+"}",
                    type: "PUT",
                    data: JSON.stringify({"read": 1}),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```

But I get an OPTION Method in the Network log in Chrome. Why?

Is the Syntax not correct?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): _The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers_

Comment: Because it's asking the server if `PUT` is supported. Have the server respond correctly to the OPTIONS request and the PUT will come.

Comment: if the answer helped you, please mark is as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do. Hope it helps:

```
var WebServiceUrl = 'SomeWebservice.asmx/SomeMethod';
var DataToSend = new Object();
DataToSend = {  
                FirstName : 'John',
                LastName : 'Smith'
             };

//Call jQuery ajax
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: WebServiceUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(DataToSend),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (err){
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

And assuming you have a Webservice. I have a simple ASP.NET VB web service: SomeWebservice.asmx and its method signature as follows:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function SomeMethod(ByVal FirstName As String, ByVal LastName As String) As String
```